# How to clear Isotope search filter with a click of a button in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to clear my search filter without deleting the texts on the search field but by using a button. The search field clears up but the whole items on the grid won't reappear.

I tried to make the clear button a part of the combination filter and add a data-filter="*" but still won't work.

```
  <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="clear">
    <a class="button" id="clearme" data-filter="">Clear</a>
  </div>
```

Here's the code that I'm using to clear the search field:

```
$('#clearme').on( 'click', function() {
    $(".quicksearch").val("");
})
```

[And here's the whole codepen](https://codepen.io/ableslayer/pen/wvMggOz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the isotope re-initialization in the other answer is that after clicking it redefines the filter function, thus the initial function that you wrote gets reset and it stops working, which is a bad idea in your specific use case.

A simple way of doing this without messing with the previously create filter function would be something like this :

```
$('#clearme').on( 'click', function() {
    $(".quicksearch").val("");
    $(".quicksearch").keyup();
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like

```
$("#clearme").click(function(){
    $(".grid").isotope({
        filter: '*'
    });
});
```

This will clear all filters.

Comment: Ok that cleared the filters but after clicking, the filtering doesn't work anymore. See updated codepen. Also, can it only filter what was inputed on the search filter? What it does is that it clears all of the filter and it also clears when you click on red and small filter button.

Comment: OK will check and get back to you.